# Endless loop with InvokeMember c#

Tags: c#, javascript, forms, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to mark some checkboxes and then submit a form using webbrowser, I succeeded, the problem is that my program is getting endless, It appears the form submitted, and then my form before being submitted, again submitted and again before being submitted and again...again....again.... infinitely so. I do not understand why.

I have realized that it happens in this part:

```
form.InvokeMember ("submit");
```

This is my code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.mysite.com");
        }

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            this.Text = e.Url.ToString() + " loaded";
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("check1").InvokeMember("CLICK");
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("check2").InvokeMember("CLICK");
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("check3").InvokeMember("CLICK");
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("check4").InvokeMember("CLICK");
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("check5").InvokeMember("CLICK");

            foreach (HtmlElement form in webBrowser1.Document.Forms)
            {
                if (form.Name == "SearchForm")
                {
                    form.InvokeMember("submit");

                }   
            }            
        }

private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = "Navigating";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you've said that *any* time you finish loading a page, you want to submit the search form. So when that submit finishes, it will finish loading the page... and you'll trigger the same event. It's an entirely natural loop.

You should ask yourself what condition you want to detect that means you should submit the form when the page has finished loading. Should it *only* be when there isn't already something in the search box, for example? Or make it change based on the URL? Or perhaps you simply want to unhook the event handler for "document completed" before you submit the form? We can't really tell without more context, but that's why you're setting that behaviour.

Comment: Hello @Jon thanks for your answer!, I just wanna load the page and after that submit the form, so I can work with the submitted form. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @VictorPCL: Yes. It sounds like you should remove the event handler within the event handler itself, so that it only fires once.

Comment: Yes @Jon it is! In which part I have to remove it? For me it seems that im not using eventhandler inside of another eventhandler. Thanks for your help Im really new in webbrowser control

Comment: @VictorPCL: In the event handler method, just have `DocumentCompleted -= webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;`. You're *implicitly* using the event handler repeatedly, because you've said "Whenever the current document finishes loading, start loading another document." So when that next document finishes loading, it will trigger the same event handler again...

Comment: Is it possible you can modify it in the code of my question? Thanks a lot again @Jon

Comment: @VictorPCL: You don't *have* an answer - you have a question. And no, there's no point in me modifying the *question* to show code that wouldn't demonstrate the problem. That statement in my previous comment is *all* you would need, at the start of the `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` method. It's very important that you *understand* it though, rather than just copying and pasting but not knowing why it works or what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Victor, try having a different form (*.aspx) for the submit action.